# Convergence of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty } \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln(n) \cdot (\ln(\ln(n)))^{a}} $

Tags: real-analysis

I have a problem with a convergence of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty } \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln(n) \cdot (\ln(\ln(n)))^{a}}$ depending on the parameter $a$. I know that  $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{1}{\ln(n)} \rightarrow 0$, but I don't know how to deal with $\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n)))^{a}}$ and how to get to the final answer. So far I solved tasks with  $\frac{1}{n ^{a}}$ and I know that $a>1  \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty }\frac{1}{n ^{a}}$ is convergent, but in this task I cannot use it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

By [**Cauchy condensation test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we can check the convergence by the condensed series $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ that is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } \frac{2^n}{2^n \cdot \ln(2^n) \cdot (\ln(\ln(2^n)))^{a}}=\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } \frac{1}{ n\ln(2) \cdot (\ln (n \ln 2))^{a}}$$

and then we can apply the test again to obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot(\ln(2^{n}\ln(2))^{a}} =\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot(\ln(2^{n})+\ln(\ln(2)) )^{a}} =$$$$=\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot n^a(\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2))/n )^{a}}$$

and for the latter we can use limit comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }\frac1{n^a}$.

Comment: Ok, so I have a $\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot(\ln(2^{n}\ln(2))^{a}}$ and $\ln(2) \rightarrow \ln(2) $, więc we have to deal only $(\ln(2^{n}\ln(2))^{a}$, but I still do not know how to do it

Comment: @MP3129 You are almost done indeed $$\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot(\ln(2^{n}\ln(2))^{a}}
=\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot(\ln(2^{n})+\ln(\ln(2)) )^{a}}
=\frac{1}{\ln(2)\cdot n^a(\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2))/n )^{a}}$$

Comment: But I don't know what I can do with $(\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2))/n)^{a}$

Comment: @MP3129 Simply note that $(\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2))/n)^{a}\to (\ln 2)^a$ then for the series we can refer to limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^a}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is set up very naturally for the integral test, after noting that the substitution $u = \ln(\ln x)$ leads to

$$\int \frac{1}{x \ln x (\ln \ln x)^{a}} \, dx = \int \frac 1 {u^a} \, du.$$

The natural caveat, however, is that your series shouldn't start at $n = 1$ because $\ln1 $ is a problem, and that $1/n \to 0$ not $\to 1$.